# Castle doctrine

Tags: self-defense

Does castle doctrine mean any guest at a house can kill uninvited guests? Is it awkward because they would have to know the guest was uninvited despite not being the property owner? Would a quick phone call be enough? Assume the uninvited guest is just some random person who entered the house and is not violent.

Comment: Does the castle doctrine mean that the owner of a house can kill uninvited guests?  In general, no.  So invited guests can't do it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does castle doctrine mean any guest at a house can kill uninvited
>   guests?

### No.

You have a completely faulty reading of the [Castle doctrine (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_doctrine).

The Castle doctrine allows a *person... protections and immunities permitting one, **in certain circumstances**, to use force...*

And, those circumstances:

> Castle doctrines lessen the duty to retreat when an individual is
>   assaulted within one's own home. Deadly force may either be
>   justified... "when the actor reasonably fears imminent peril of death
>   or serious bodily harm to him or herself or another"...

While

> Castle doctrines may not provide civil immunity, such as from wrongful death
>   suits, which have a much lower burden of proof.

**Aspects of the castle doctrine vary according to jurisdiction.**

Comment: You might add an explicit answer to the question, which would of course be "no."

Comment: Good point; and I just learned how to use H tags.